# How to returning WCF Service POST response as JSON

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

i have created WCF Service with POST request.

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         //  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
         UriTemplate = "/UpdateRCFOnline"
         )]
        String UpdateRCFOnline(RCFOnline rcf_class);

  public string UpdateRCFOnline(RCFOnline rcf_class)
    {
        string success = string.empty;
                
        try
        {
            //POST data to DB
            success = "Update Success";
        } catch(Exception ex){
            success = "Update Failed, " +ex.message;
        }
        
    return success;
    
    }
```

How to make this POST request returning "Success" as JSON. Cause if i tried this service in Fiddler. I got message on "Raw" tab not JSON.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
public object UpdateRCFOnline(RCFOnline rcf_class)
{     
    try
    {
        //POST data to DB
        return new {
           success = "Update Success";
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        return new {
           success = "Update Failed, " +ex.message;
        }
    }

}
```

This way you are returning an object which will be deserialised to json string.

Note. also check if you can set return `data type` to json

Comment: if you can define return data object class will be even better